# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:36059 Ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

So, my code is as follows

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc2
options = uc2.ChromeOptions()

browser=uc2.Chrome(options=options,enable_cdp_event=True,executable_path='/home/pablo/Escritorio/chromedriver')
```

and it throws the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:34959
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
Current browser version is 99.0.4844.84
```

Now the first time it happened I updated chrome just by running in ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and now if I do

```
google-chrome --version

>>Google Chrome 100.0.4896.60
```

Yet, the exact same error is happening. Why is it pointing to a chrome version that no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you haven't updated your browser. Update Chrome.

Comment: showing up for me with latest version

Comment: Updating didn't work out for me.